# mySQL PHP separate terms in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have multiple entries in a mysql table field, these are separated with commas;
`data1, data2, data3` etc. How do I using PHP separate out these terms and display them separately in a table like so;

```
Data
------------
Data 1
------------
Data 2
------------
Data 3
------------
etc
```

Comment: You shouldn't have multiple entries in a mysql table field seprated with commas. But separate TABLE where these entries stored in rows

Comment: .. or a column per piece of data in a single table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't have multiple values in a single column. However, regardless of why you have it, there is a function in php called `explode` which allows you to explode a string at a specific delimiter. You can have something like this: `$myArray = explode(',', $mydata_coming_from_database);`

Answer (score 2):

After retrieval of data from database,You can use explode() function to create an array and loop that array.I think It will help you.

Answer (score 1):

explode() is you one and only option